# Need pointer or suggestion on Regex to find out if the string has int(int)

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

Need pointer or suggestion on Regex and code to find out if the string has int(int) only  for example :

"3(3)"  : Should return **true**
"-3(1)" : should return **true**
"2(1)"  : should return **true**
"Hello 2(7)" : Should return **false** as String should only contain int(int)
"1(7) 2(3)" : **False** as String should only contain one set of int(int).
Any pointer will be helful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
^-{0,1}\d+\(-{0,1}\d+\)$
```

`^` match the start of the string

`-{0,1}` match 0 or 1 "-" sign

`\d+` match one or more digits

`\(` and `\)` match literal open close parenthesis

`$` match the end of the string, ensuring we only match the exact pattern

Live example

https://regex101.com/r/vTwue0/2

Comment: @GirirajBanshiwala you can click the check mark to mark it as the accepted answer if this solves your problem

Comment: `{0,1}` is not wrong, but personally I would've just used `?`.  It's a little more readable IMO.  Good answer though